# Entity Framework C# Table does not updated with data in using add method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have followed by this tutorial

youtube.com/watch?v=K4x6eoG7hwY&ab_channel=SeeSharpCode

But still cant add data to my table.
I did not do any manual change on this EF Code
I did like on the tutorial but still cant add data to my table..

And this is all the code I have written:

my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTest](
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

my code :

```
using (Database1Entities database1Entities = new Database1Entities())            {
                TableTest t = new TableTest
                {
                    Name = "name1"
                };
                database1Entities.TableTest.Add(t);
                int c = database1Entities.TableTest.Count();
                database1Entities.SaveChanges();
            }
```

on the next line, c variable get value of 0...    If it can help to understand the problem

```
int c = database1Entities.TableTest.Count();
```

Add `TableTestModel.Context.cs` class

```
public partial class Database1Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Database1Entities()
            : base("name=Database1Entities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<TableTest> TableTest { get; set; }
    }
```

In addition I am using

This app config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TableTestModel.csdl|res://*/TableTestModel.ssdl|res://*/TableTestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.7.0" newVersion="3.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And using a local SQL Database  with name `Database1.mdf`

Answer (score 1):

You have not yet completed the transaction when you ask the DB the entities count, change to this and tell me if it works:

```
using (Database1Entities database1Entities = new Database1Entities())            {
                TableTest t = new TableTest
                {
                    Name = "name1"
                };
                database1Entities.TableTest.Add(t);
                database1Entities.SaveChanges(); <----- HERE
                int c = database1Entities.TableTest.Count();
            }
```

Comment: You right about the count..  but it still not add the new data to my table in the database..

Comment: Use 'database1Entities.Add(t);' without the entity refercence, in case it does't work can i see your dbcontext? (remember to hide your connection string)

Comment: I have add it to my main question\

Comment: Yes I add a new data to it manualy

Its link to picture it this
https://prnt.sc/uc0jf0

Comment: Try to do: int c = database1Entities.TableTest.ToList().Count();

Comment: If the database is not being updated then this is typically a case where your connection string is pointing at a database other than what you are expecting. With the default constructor it will be using a connection string from your config called "Database1Entities" which may be pointing at a different database/server than what you are checking. As a test you can pass a connection string to the DbContext constructor to force it to a specific location.

Comment: Good call Steve

Comment: @StevePy  Hi I have added a row to my table manually and try database1Entities.TableTest.ToList().First().Name its return the right value that I have added which means the connection string is it right. right?

Comment: it is, i think that the reason is because you asked to .net the count of an IQuerable, that do not hold values, works as a framwork in shich the values will be loaded after

Comment: ps. Upvote the correct answer please :) i need the points for been able to comment

Comment: But my problem still unsolved..  I cant add new data to my table in the database using EF

Comment: So you still can't send data to the db, but the counting is correct? have you tried to write " 'database1Entities.Add(t);" instead of 'database1Entities.TableTest.Add(t);" ?

Comment: @Red  Yes, my counting is correct but can't add data to my database
'database1Entities.Add' this method does not exist...

Comment: EF core or 6? in my app is context.Add(entitiy)

Comment: @red I have EF 6

Comment: That's why, i was assuming you were using EFC as me. I don't know then

Comment: Ah, ok that Connection string is using the EDMX designer. What's likely happening is you are looking at the designer database instance that gets created, but the application at runtime is possibly creating/linking to an instance of the database (Database1.mdf) in a different data directory. (I.e. possibly under the /bin/debug/ directory?) From your solution directory, do a search for Database1.mdf to see if there is another copy that the app has created. It's been ages since I used EDMXs, opting to just create the DB manually and point EF at it with mappings for the tables.

Comment: @StevePy  Man your a genius...  I have no worlds...